# How to install the latest Mumble Server?

Tags: server, mumble

How to install the latest version of the Mumble Server in Ubuntu Server 11.04 and configure it correctly. I have tried several times and it didn't work out properly.

Comment: Still looking for a answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 9.10, 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04 Install the PPA from here: https://launchpad.net/~slicer/+archive/ppa

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slicer/ppa`

Then just update the repositories and install the `mumble-server` package

For 11.10 and future versions it is in the official repos:

`sudo apt-get install mumble-server` (For the Server)

`sudo apt-get install mumble-server-web` (For the Server Web interface)

`sudo apt-get install mumble` (For the Client)